# Utilize glOrtho function after drawing without redrawing entire screen

Tags: python, opengl

I am creating a fractal engine in python using OpenGL. I essentially create a string representing the fractal, then iterate over that string and parse it into a series of points which lines are drawn between. Because of the nature of fractals, I am not aware of what size the fractal takes up until after I have drawn the fractal and obtained the minimum and maximum X and Y values. However, in order to do this introduces an increase in time to run. I was attempting to refactor my code to cut out this step but ran into a roadblock upon trying to refresh the window and scale for the fractal using the glOrtho method. The code essentially operates like this:

```
def setup():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    Declared current state variables, curr_x, curr_y, etc

    for i in range(len(current_state)): #current_state is the fractal string
        term = current_state[i]
        old_x = curr_x
        old_y = curr_y

        if term == 'f' or term == '!':
            curr_x, curr_y = f_const(curr_x, curr_y, curr_angle, curr_gen)
            drawLine([old_x, old_y, curr_x, curr_y])
        if term == '+':
            curr_angle = turn_right(curr_angle)
        if term == '-':
            curr_angle = turn_left(curr_angle)
        etc...
        if curr_x > x_max:
            x_max = curr_x
        if curr_x < x_min:
            x_min = curr_x
        if curr_y > y_max:
            y_max = curr_y
        if curr_y < y_min:
            y_min = curr_y

    refresh2d()
    glutSwapBuffers()

def refresh2d():
    global x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def drawLine(points):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex2f(points[0], points[1])
    glVertex2f(points[2], points[3])
    glEnd()
```

As it is, it fails to draw properly. If I move the refresh2d() call to above the for loop and hardcode min and max values, it works, but when the call is at the bottom, it does not resize until I change the window in some way, such as maximizing it. If what I am asking is possible and anyone has any suggestions, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> If what I am asking is possible

No, it is not. At least not at this level. OpenGL is just a rendering API. It does not manage scenes or objects. It is designed as a state machine, where you have operations to set/change some state variables, and *draw calls* which are affected by the state you did set *before*.

All what `glOrtho` does is modifying a matrix. That matrix is used during draw calls by applying it to all vertex positions - but changing the matrix does not in any way modify the content in the frame buffer. It just affects the draw calls following it.

However, you do not have to completely re-parse you fractal. You could also just store the actual vertex data in a [Vertex Buffer Object (VBO)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) and simpy re-draw that with a different matrix.

Note that the GL you are using is completely *outdated* and *deprecated* since over a decade by now. There is no built-in matrix stack in modern core profiles GL, and also no fixed-function pipeline. YOu would have to write your own shaders, and add your own parameters for the transformations (and also gain complete freedom about all those steps). So if you really want to write new GL code in 2019, I can only advise you to learn the (already decade old) "modern" way of using a core profile...

Comment: Thanks for the response, in that case, is there a different library for graphics that you would recommend, my only realistic requirement is the ability to draw large numbers of lines in a 2d space with some way to scale the image in post

Comment: Well, I have no idea what graphics libraries exist which might better fit your needs. However, drawing a set of 2D lines is something which can be done with OpenGL quite well, it is also not that hard with modern GL. However "with some way to scale the image in post" do you actually want to just scale the_image_, or do you want to re-render a different section of it? Both can be done with GL, and what I told about in my answer is basically the most straight-forward approach of the second option.

Comment: Ok, the constraint I have run into is that I don't know the dimensions until all lines have been drawn. Meaning I cannot define a matrix ahead of time. My goal is to minimize runtime. My computer is currently being held hostage while gathering data from the current iteration of the program. I will research VBOs while I wait, thanks.